# Issue with running Linux Audit System in a nested Virtual Machine inside Google Cloud Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, auditd

I am trying to run the Linux audit system in a nested Virtual machine on the google cloud engine.  The problem I am facing is that the Linux Audit System suspends after showing the following error after a few minutes when I view the auditd status.

```
جنوری 29 16:53:42 fuzzer-VirtualBox auditd[294]: Audit daemon has no space left on logging partition

جنوری 29 16:53:42 fuzzer-VirtualBox auditd[294]: Audit daemon is suspending logging due to no space left on logging partition
```

I checked using the df -h command and found out that there were around 6GB of free space on the logging partition so I did not understand why this error is occurring. Can you provide me a solution? Could this be because of nested virtualization?

Below is my auditd.conf:

```
#
# This file controls the configuration of the audit daemon
#

local_events = yes
write_logs = yes
log_file = /var/log/audit/audit.log
log_group = adm
log_format = RAW
flush = INCREMENTAL_ASYNC
freq = 50
max_log_file = 24
num_logs = 50
priority_boost = 4
disp_qos = lossy
dispatcher = /sbin/audispd
name_format = NONE
##name = mydomain
max_log_file_action = keep_logs
space_left = 75
space_left_action = SYSLOG
verify_email = yes
action_mail_acct = root
admin_space_left = 50
admin_space_left_action = SUSPEND
disk_full_action = SUSPEND
disk_error_action = SUSPEND
use_libwrap = yes
##tcp_listen_port = 60
tcp_listen_queue = 5
tcp_max_per_addr = 1
##tcp_client_ports = 1024-65535
tcp_client_max_idle = 0
enable_krb5 = no
krb5_principal = auditd
##krb5_key_file = /etc/audit/audit.key
distribute_network = no
```

Below are my parameters in audit.rules file:

```
## First rule - delete all
-D

## Buffer size
-b 8192

## This determine how long to wait in burst of events
--backlog_wait_time 0

## Set failure mode to syslog
-f 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message, you should you try to:

- Clear unwanted files from `/var` to recover free space.
- Increase the size of `/var` file system.
- The `/etc/audit/auditd.conf` configuration file contains the `space_left` option which describes numeric value in megabytes that tells the audit daemon when to perform a configurable action because the system is starting to run low on disk space. Check `auditd.conf` man page for more information on possible actions and their behavior.

This could be caused by:

- The `/var file` system does not have enough free space.
- The auditd daemon writes "*Audit daemon is low on disk space for logging*" in messages log file when the log destination file system does not have enough free space.

[Reference](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/53251)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably out of inodes, that also manifests as ENOSPC.

```
df -i
```

should be able to tell you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have checked and there are plenty of free inodes available.